# Javascript function is not verifying a form

Tags: javascript, html

i have this form:

```
<form id="frm_register" action="register.php" method="post" onsubmit ="return register_user()">
    <label for="txtuname" style="display: block; width: 80px; float: left;">Username: </label>
    <input id="txtuname" name="ntxtuname" type="text" style="" /><br /><br /> 
    <label for="txtupwd" style="display: block; width: 80px; float: left;">Password: </label>
    <input id="txtupwd" name="ntxtupwd" type="password" style="" /><br /><br />
    <label for="txtuemail" style="display: block; width: 80px; float: left;">Email: </label>
    <input id="txtuemail" name="ntxtuemail" type="text" style="width:200px;" /><br /><br />
    <label for="txtpayza" style="display: block; width: 80px; float: left;">Payza: </label>                                
    <input id="txtpayza" name="ntxtpayza" type="text" style="width:200px;" /><br /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" style="margin-left: 250px;"/>
</form>
```

And a JavaScript function to verify the form before submit:

```
<script type="javascript/text">          
    function register_user() {
        if(document.frm_register.ntxtuname.value=='') {
            alert('wrong');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

But still the form submits and no verification is done. What is wrong with this picture guys?

Comment: do you know what does this do document.wrapper.page.content.frm_register

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work after fixing 2 errors, which has been verified on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzheng/kPzcV/).

**First**:

```
<script type="javascript/text">
```

should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Otherwise the Javascript code won't be recognized.

**Second**:

```
document.frm_register
```

should be:

```
document.getElementById("frm_register")
```

or:

```
document.forms.frm_register
```

Otherwise it will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to search for textbox value thru form?

Instead of this

```
if(document.frm_register.ntxtuname.value=='')
```

you can do this

```
if(document.getElementById("ntxtuname").value==="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the verification to be called on the click of the submit buton

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" 
         style="margin-left: 250px;" onclick="return register_user()"/>
```

This should take care of it.